# Passing __FILE__ macro as an argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macros

I'm trying to create a function in Objective-C that will take `__FILE__` and _cmd as arguments to prepare them for a Flurry logging event.

Here's my function signature:

`NSDictionary *prepareFailedRequestData(ASIFormDataRequest *request, char file, SEL method);`

I'm not sure what to type the 'file' argument as. I tried 'unsigned char' based on some documentation I found, but that, as well as my current implementation, are throwing compiler warnings and crashing the program.

If 'file' will be the output of the `__FILE__` macro, how do I type my argument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//You would need to do something like this
const char *currentFile=__FILE__;
```

Is a constant string, from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html):

> This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form
>   of a C string constant. This is the path by which the preprocessor
>   opened the file, not the short name specified in `#include' or as the
>   input file name argument. For example, "/usr/local/include/myheader.h"
>   is a possible expansion of this macro.

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` expands to a literal string, like `"MyFile.m"`, so you would normally use `const char *` as the type:

```
NSDictionary *prepareFailedRequestData(ASIFormDataRequest *request,
    const char *file, SEL method);
```

Comment: precisely so. Logic suggests that file will be a String (c-style string in this case) with the name/path+name of the file. A single char is well, 'A' or similar. char* or char[] will work (I'm not sure if Objective-C is ok with char[] though, so char* is best ^^)